# Is there a python function which gives me the "minimal list of lists"?

Tags: python, list

Given a list of lists (e.g. the `input_ls` below): Do you know of a function which gives me the minimal list of lists (as a dictionary), with which I can construct the initial `input_ls` by "adding up" those lists (e.g. the `output_dict` below)?

```
input_ls = [
    ['apple', 'banana', 'coconut', 'strawberry', 'mango'],
    ['banana', 'coconut', 'strawberry'],
    ['mango'],
    ['coconut', 'strawberry', 'mango'],
    ['apple', 'banana']
    ]

output_dict = {
    1: ['mango'],
    2: ['apple'],
    3: ['banana'],
    4: ['coconut', 'strawberry']
    }
```

Edit:
What do I mean that: Which sublists of the lists in `input_ls` are necessary, so that by adding up those sublists result in any any list of the `input_ls`, e.g. I need the list `['banana']` and `['coconut', 'strawberry']` of the `output_dict` to construct `['banana', 'coconut', 'strawberry']` of the `input_ls`. List `'coconut'` and `'strawberry'` comes only in pair, so therefore I cannot split them up.

Comment: Can you explain the rules that are used to determine what the output is?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will try to elaborate my thoughts.

Comment: That's much better. And an interesting mathematical question. I'm sure there's an abstract algebraic term for what you're trying to do right now, but I can't come up with it off the top of my head.

Comment: I'm not following. How are you supposed to convert `output_dict` back into `input_ls`? What do the numbers in `output_dict` mean? And what's the purpose of this anyway? You might want to add context to make sure you're not experiencing an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832).

Comment: BTW, if order isn't important and items can't appear more than once, it'd make more sense to use lists of [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's record for each word what documents it appears in:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def get_postings(docs):
  postings = defaultdict(list)
  for i, doc in enumerate(docs):
    for word in doc:
      postings[word].append(i)
  return postings
```

Let's apply it to our input to see what we get:

```py
>>> p = get_postings(input_ls)
>>> p
defaultdict(list,
            {'apple': [0, 4],
             'banana': [0, 1, 4],
             'coconut': [0, 1, 3],
             'strawberry': [0, 1, 3],
             'mango': [0, 2, 3]})
```

The second stage is to group words by their document lists:

```py
def get_groups(postings):
  groups = defaultdict(list)
  for k, v in postings.items():
    groups[tuple(v)].append(k)
  return groups
```

Now we get the dict of these "minimal lists" but the keys are the document lists themselves:

```py
>>> g = get_groups(p)
>>> g
defaultdict(list,
            {(0, 4): ['apple'],
             (0, 1, 4): ['banana'],
             (0, 1, 3): ['coconut', 'strawberry'],
             (0, 2, 3): ['mango']})
```

At this point you could still reconstruct your original documents using the keys and the values but if you want your keys to be plain integers, there is another step left:

```py
>>> {i: x for i, x in enumerate(g.values())}
{0: ['apple'], 1: ['banana'], 2: ['coconut', 'strawberry'], 3: ['mango']}
```